# Textarea: обработка данных из формы

Tags: textarea

Как обрабатывать данные вписанные в форме Textarea ?

Например после нажатия кнопки отправить мне нужно что бы текст был присвоен переменной которую можно было бы потом обрабатывать Ну например сохранить в файл.

Был бы очень признателен за демо скрипт с описанием тегов функций и операторов

Comment: Не поленитесь хотя бы назвать язык, на котором вы хотите это делать.

Comment: Ой я извиняюсь ))) PHP

Answer (score 2):

```
<textarea name='sometext'></textarea>
<? $var = $_POST['sometext'] // записываем в переменную отправленную информацию ?>
```

Comment: Я уже разобрался где у меня была ошибка ))) Го всё равно спасибо )))